# Why does usePage().props break my website?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm a beginner in Laravel/InertiaJS. I'm following the tutorial at [Laravel Bootcamp](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/inertia/editing-chirps#updating-our-component).

The following line of code makes the screen load blank, with no errors. If I comment this line out, it loads normally.

```
const { auth } = usePage().props;
```

Here's my code:

HandleInertiaRequests.php

```
public function share(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'auth' => [
            'user' => $request->user(),
        ],
        'ziggy' => function () {
            return (new Ziggy)->toArray();
        },
    ]);
}
```

.

Controller

```
public function index(): Response
{
    return Inertia::render('Chirps/Index', [
        'chirps' => Chirp::with('user:id,name')->latest()->get(),
    ]);
}
```

.

Chirps/Index Component

```
export default function Index({ auth, chirps }) {
    const { data, setData, post, processing, reset, errors } = useForm({
        message: '',
    });

    ...

    return (
        <Authenticated auth={auth}>
                ...
                    {chirps.map(chirp =>
                        <Chirp key={chirp.id} chirp={chirp} />
                    )}
                ...
        </Authenticated>
    );
}
```

.

Chirp Component (with the error)

```
export default function Chirp({ chirp }) {
    // The page loads normally when I comment out the line below. Otherwise it loads blank with no error.
    const { auth } = usePage().props;

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

.

I think I've included everything important above. Please tell me if I'm missing anything.

I need to know: Doesn't why this line of code from Laravel Bootcamp work?

Bonus points: Why am I not getting an error?

EDIT: I'm getting errors in the browser console.

```
Uncaught Error: usePage must be used within the Inertia component
```

Comment: Have you checked errors in browser devtools?

Comment: Does `usePage` work in `Index` component?

Comment: The same thing happens when I put `usePage` in the `Index` component.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In the end the problem was changing:

```
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
```

to

```
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';
```

in my `app.tsx` (or `app.js` if you are not using typescript)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).